# Add JavaScript object to form data while submit the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

The user has the option to perform several actions in the form, after action when he submits the form, needs to add a JavaScript object to form. I tried multiple ways, in server data reached as `[Object object]`

**JavaScript Object**

```
var damageitems = {'5b3b43285d57025915000002':
                  {action: "accept",damage_location_name:"Front Bumper", estimated_total_repair_cost: "993.72", estimated_total_repair_cost_currency:"USD"}
                  }
```

**Script I tried**

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        url = $(this).attr( "action" );
        var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
        postData.push({name: 'damage_items', value: damage_items});
        $.post(url, postData, function(){});
    });
```

**Value reached in server**

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"uztc+G0fyTb8wH7D6HZAslTfxuJvFLP3UunjiRjWylk=", "damage_items"=>"[object Object]", "action"=>"batch_update", "controller"=>"damage_items", "claim_id"=>"5b3b41415d57026665000001"}
```

My aims submit the value as normal submit not ajax,
the value in js variable reaches in the server as a hash with key `damage_items`.
Not prefer the way add it in form control value then submit

Comment: [`jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). `data` must be of type [PlainObject](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject) or string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating your script to the following will do the trick

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    url = $(this).attr( "action" );
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    postData.push({name: 'damage_items', value: JSON.stringify(damage_items)});
    $.post(url, postData, function(){});
});
```

When you try to store the data in the form, it is converted into a string using toString method if it is not a string already. toString method of Object returns `[object Object]` and that is why you are getting it.

Converting it into a JSON string will prevent that.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to turn a JavaScript Object Literal into a [JSON](https://www.json.org/) (see the differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)). Because *It is easy for machines to parse and generate* and most of server side languages have methods to parse it. Also in http requests, like ajax, we **must** send strings.

Fortunately we have a method in js to do that, and is using [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and a method to turn a JSON into JavaScript Object Literal using [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Then, in your code:

```js
//JavaScript Object Literal
var damageitems = {'5b3b43285d57025915000002':
                  {action: "accept",damage_location_name:"Front Bumper", estimated_total_repair_cost: "993.72", estimated_total_repair_cost_currency:"USD"}
                  }


damageitems = JSON.stringify(damageitems);


//JSON - It is easy for machines to parse and generate
// we could put this in a request because it's a string,
console.log(damageitems);
```